# SQL to populate a hyperlink column in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I imagine the SQL must pass 2 values, the value shown in the table and the link to which that value navigates.

I'd appreciate a pointer to the SQL Script for achieving this. Thanks.

Comment: In what context are you running the SQL? If it's within Access, you can use the built-in functions for dealing with hyperlinks. If you're using ODBC or OLEDB, those are unavailable. As @Remou says below, hyperlink fields offer very little benefit even within Access, but outside of it, they are worse still -- you should avoid using them, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format for a hyperlink column (field) is:

Description#Address#

For example:

```
This is StackOverflow#http://stackoverflow.com#
Mr E Xample#mailto:example@example.com#
```

For the most part, I prefer to avoid hyperlink fields (columns) as editing them is a real problem. A text or memo field with a little code is much simpler, though you will need a form.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

This is not critical (since I can use string functions to separate the two strings) but is it possible to use SQL to separate the Description from the Address (without using string functions) from C#?

Comment: Outside of a control, not that I know of, but that is not saying much :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a query to extract the Description and Address from a hyperlink field, try this:

```
SELECT
    hlink,
    Left(hlink,InStr(1,hlink,"#")-1) AS link_description,
    Mid(hlink,InStr(1,hlink,"#")+1,InStr(InStr(1,hlink,"#")+1,hlink,"#")-InStr(1,hlink,"#")-1) AS link_address
FROM tblHyperlink;
```

It's sure not pretty.  And it will return #Error for hyperlink fields which are Null or contain less than two # characters.

Comment: A hyperlink field is just a memo field with a set of attributes that make the Access application treat it differently.