# ASP.net databinding a hyperlink from Access DB fields

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I am helping my daughter build an asp.net website that has an Access database.  We are using a DataList with a couple fields inside the ItemTemplate.  The one that is giving me trouble is the Hyperlink.   The code is below.  When the page loads the hyperlink renders like this:

```
 <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_lnk_6" href="#http://www.washingtonfaire.com/#" target="_blank">Washington Midsummer Renaissance Faire</a>
```

But when I click on the link, it tries to navigate to "http://localhost:1852/BOOMPiratesB/Raids.aspx#http://www.washingtonfaire.com/#"

What are we doing wrong?

Here is our code.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1"> 
        <ItemTemplate> 
                  <asp:HyperLink id="lnk" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Link") %>' Target="_blank" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "VenueName")%>'> 
                  </asp:HyperLink> 

                  <br /> 
            <asp:Label ID="DateTextLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateText") %>' /> 
            <br /> 
            <asp:Label ID="CityStateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CityState") %>' /> 
            <br /> 
<br /> 
        </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:DataList> 
    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server"  
        DataFile="~/App_Data/my.mdb"  
        SelectCommand="SELECT [VenueName], [Link], [DateText], [Season], [DateStart], [CityState] FROM [qpgRaid]"> 
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

I cannot see where the extra # signs are coming from.  They don't appear to be in the field in the table.

It's very puzzling.  And insight would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449034/sql-to-populate-a-hyperlink-column-in-ms-access)

I guess you are using an access hyperlink column to store the link. If you convert it to a text column it should start working fine, or you may have to strip the '#'s manually.

Comment: I made it a memo field and then stripped the # signs out. That seemes to work. Thanks.