# Save text as a hyperlink style for Access and C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
private void button1_Click(objectsender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        OpenFileDialogdlg = newOpenFileDialog();

        dlg.Filter = "JPGFiles(*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files(*.png)|*.png|All Files(*.*)|*.*";

        if(dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            stringpicLoc = dlg.FileName.ToString();

            txt_image.Text = picLoc;

            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = picLoc;
        }
    }
}
```

The command above will create a image path on the textbox(txt_image).

And when clicking save, the command is shown as below:

```
command.CommandText = "insert into RecordsSheet ([Picture]) values('" + txt_image.Text + "')";
```

Then an error occur saying that "Data type mismatch in criteria expression, since the "Picture" column setting in MS Access is Hyperlink.

I am not sure what to do to insert the data as a hyperlink, instead of a text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL to populate a hyperlink column in MS Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449034/sql-to-populate-a-hyperlink-column-in-ms-access)